# CFPDF or Java: get trimbox size of pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, coldfusion

The [cfpdf](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7995.html)'s PageSizes array is returning mediabox sizes, but I need to get the [trimbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/X).

[image: example output of cfpdf]

Is it possible to get the trimbox with ColdFusion (or Java) without the use of console tools like imagemagick (and cfexecute)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cfpdf's PageSizes array actually returns cropbox dimesions.

Though CF doesn't expose trimbox directly, you can use underlying java object to get the same. If you read the PDF in a variable with say cfpdf action read, the variable is just a wrapper on a PDFDocument (Documented with LiveCycle). The pseudo code would be like following:

```
pageTree = varname.getDoc().requirePages();

page = pageTree.getPage(index);

trimBox = page.getTrimBox().getValues();

height = trimBox[4] - trimBox[2];

width = trimBox[3] - trimBox[1];
```

HTH,
Chandan Kumar

p.s. uses non-documented api

Comment: (Edit). Good tip. I did not know that one. Quick question, can `getTrimBox().getValues();` ever be null/undefined?

Comment: According to PDF reference 1.7 a media box is a required entry in a page object.

(Required; inheritable) A rectangle (see Section 3.8.4, “Rectangles”), expressed in default user space units, defining the boundaries of the physical medium on which the page is intended to be displayed or printed (see Section 10.10.1, “Page Boundaries”).

However not all PDF generation software adhere to spec. Its ideal to use a null or isdefined check before using the values.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the older version of iText bundled with CF. Load the file into a `PdfReader` object. Then use [`PdfReader.getBoxSize(int index,String boxName)`](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#getBoxSize%28int,%20String%29) to grab the trimbox for each page (it may be null) and extract the width and height.

Here is an example tested with CF9:

```
<cfscript>
    path = "C:/path/to/file.pdf";
    reader = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader").init( path );

    sizes = [];
    for (i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        //note: the trimbox may be null / undefined
        rect = reader.getBoxSize( i, "trim");
        if (structKeyExists(variables, "rect")) {
            arrayAppend(sizes, {height=rect.getHeight(), width=rect.getWidth()});
        }
    }

    WriteDump(sizes);
</cfscript>
```